# DFS search not returning certain nodes in my list

Tags: python, search, depth-first-search

I'm using this implementation for DFS to get the nodes of the root I specify in the function, but for the adjLists1 i'm using I a error when I call 2 as the root. . 1 and 3 return their child nodes but 2 doesn't. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. 
The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2  5    File "DFS2.py", line 42, in <module>
    dfs_iterative(adjLists1, 2)
  File "DFS2.py", line 17, in dfs_iterative
    if(not visited[w]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Program:

```
def dfs_iterative(adjLists, s):
    stack = []
    stack.append(s)
    n = len(adjLists)
    visited = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        visited.append(False)

    while(len(stack)>0):
        v = stack.pop()
        if(not visited[v]):
            visited[v] = True
            print(v, " ", end='')

            stack_aux = []
            for w in adjLists[v]:
                if(not visited[w]):
                    stack_aux.append(w)
            while(len(stack_aux)>0):
                stack.append(stack_aux.pop())


# ------------------------------------------------------------------

#                0      1     2      3    4        5         6        7   8
adjLists1 = [ [1,2,3], [4], [5,6], [7,8], [], [9,10,11], [12,13,14], [], [] ]

dfs_iterative(adjLists1, 2)
```

Comment: Your adjacency list contains 9 elements (inner -lists).  Therefore n is equal to 9 and you created a visited array of length 9.  But when you try and kick off a DFS from Node 2, you go to 5,6.  Then you try and explore 6, which leads you to Nodes 12,13,14.  There no 14th element in your visited list.

Comment: I see now. I added empty elements in the list to extend the length to 14 and now I can see the child nodes. Not a great fix but it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem without the blank child nodes, by using the maximum value in the list and guard against indexing appropriately:

Your code can also be simplified a bit:

```
import itertools as it

def dfs_iterative(adjLists, s):
    stack = [s]
    n = len(adjLists)
    visited = [False] * (max(it.chain(*adjLists))+1)

    while stack:
        v = stack.pop()
        if visited[v]:
            continue

        visited[v] = True
        print(v, " ", end='')
        if v >= n:   # Guard against trying to index with v
            continue
        for w in adjLists[v]:
            stack.append(w)

>>> adjLists1 = [ [1,2,3], [4], [5,6], [7,8], [], [9,10,11], [12,13,14], [], []]
>>> dfs_iterative(adjLists1, 2)
2  6  14  13  12  5  11  10  9
```

Note: You never index 0 so [1, 2, 3] is never explored.